# How to add reference to resource folder when generating dll file using IKVM

Tags: java, .net, ikvm, languagetool

I have some resources e.g. xml files, images etc in `org\languagetool\resource` directory in my jars applications directory.

I wonder how to provide reference to these resources when building dll from a jar file.
I tried adding following options:
 `-externalresource:org/languagetool/resources=org/languagetool/resources/`
and
 `-resource:org/languagetool/resources=org/languagetool/resources/`

but both seems does not to work.

My Command is as follows:

```
ikvmc.exe -target:library -out:LanguageTool.dll -resource:org/languagetool/rules=org/languagetool/rules/ -resource:org/languagetool/resources=org/languagetool/resources/ LanguageTool.jar
```

PS: I am creating dll for LanguageTools library 
http://www.languagetool.org/

Comment: Have you managed to create the DLL? Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

The -externalresource: and -resource: options both are for individual files only, so if you want multiple resources, you have to include all of them explicitly (by specifying the option multiple times).

Comment: Hi Jeroen, does the -resource option still work this way in 7.3.4830.0?  Should I expect to see the resulting resources in Visual Studio's object browser, when I browse the resulting dll?  thanks .. Jason